# How to increase the max number of columns in RMariaDB?

Tags: rmariadb

I am trying to write a table with more than 1000 columns to a MariaDB table:

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
    drv = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
    mysql=F, 
...
  )

tab <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:1600,ncol=1600,nrow=1) )
names(tab)=paste0("X",1:1600)
dbWriteTable(conn,"test",tab,overwrite=T)
```

This gives me:
`Error: Too many columns [1117]`.

Is there any way to increase the column limit?

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116439/156305. It seems to me that that is a database setting; that error is not found in the `DBI` or `RMariaDB` packages, so it's unlikely to be immediately controllable by R.

Comment: This is an InnoDB limit; other storage engines may allow more columns.  maybe try aria?

Comment: In MySQL workbench I only have a couple of options like MyISAM, which gives the same error. The DB is at AWS RDS. Is it possible to change it there? @ysth

Comment: huh; I thought you'd get the 1117 error when the table was created, not inserted; I don't know R, which does dbWriteTable do?

Comment: maybe try with append TRUE and a myisam or aria table created ahead of time?

Comment: Yes @ysth, that works, thanks! I did CREATE TABLE ... ENGINE = MyISAM ahead of time and then I could append to it. aria was not available to me. Want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: aria is available to you, just not using mysql workbench's tools.  aria is mariadb's crash-safe version of myisam.  even using workbench, you should be able to enter a CREATE TABLE request that uses it.

Comment: interesting - I got `Unknown storage engine 'aria' [1286]` @ysth

Comment: that's super weird, unless you are running a very very old version.  what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the doc correctly, dbWriteTable used like this will create the table, and that create table will, I'm guessing, use your default storage engine, InnoDB.  InnoDB has a 1000 column limit, but other storage engines have higher limits; mariadb may have an overall limit of 4096.

If you call dbWriteTable with append TRUE, it reuses an existing table if it can; try explicitly creating a table with the myisam or aria storage engine (and delete the table contents before calling dbWriteTable if appropriate).

Comment: Yes @ysth, that works, thanks! I did CREATE TABLE ... ENGINE = MyISAM ahead of time and then I could append to it. aria was not available to me.